# Azure: Deploying a Ruby on Rails app in the Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

I've just completed an automation script that:

- downloads a project build to local storage (worker role)
- installs ruby, apache, and other dependencies
- configures apache and the RoR application to serve requests via port 81

This is all working locally.  I'm working with visual studio; running the application successfully pulls the local machine from "blank slate" to "serving requests".

I'm now trying to push this up to Azure - no longer using the local machine, but an actual worker role.

I've packaged the project and uploaded it to a production environment via my Azure subscription portal, but navigating to the site URL doesn't give me anything (site not found).

I'm a bit new to Azure.  What steps do I need to take to ensure that this application will work up in the cloud?  I feel like I've forgotten to configure something, like the endpoint port (81).  Any advice or recommended reading would be super helpful; thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some real assistance to troubleshoot the problem, tt would be best to see the following 3 things:

1. Your automation script (Startup Task)
2. Your worker role OnStart() function
3. Your ServiceDefinition and ServieConfiguration

Are you using ProgramEntryPoint to luanch your RoR app or you are doing all of this in Startup task? Based on above info, it is easy to understand the application architecture and some suggestions can be made.

However, the best way to troubleshoot this problem is to [enabled RDP access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/03/setting-rdp-access-in-windows-azure-application-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-3-1-4.aspx) to your Azure Worker Role VM and then Log into your Azure VM to understand what is going on. RDP access to Azure VM will validate that your install script ran correctly and all the modules were started.

As your are new to Windows Azure there could be several things could be missing and if you provide more info you will get accurate help instead of some guess work.

Comment: Thanks so much Avkash.  I've enabled RDP access in VS, though now when I upload the package to my subscription via the portal, the deployment fails.  I'll mark this as complete and post another question :).  Thanks again for your time sir!